# How to profile tensorflow memory?

Tags: python, tensorflow

No thanks to the wonderful [tensorflow profiler documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler) displaying features rather than how the actual thing can be used. I'm experiencing a memory leak which I described earlier in my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68349724/memory-leak-that-persists-after-colab-cell-executes). I've been trying to find a way to profile memory of the things going on inside a `tf.function` ever since. But as it has always been the case, the documentation is as useless as never existing. For those who ever experienced memory leaks while using `tf.function`, is there a way to actually see what memory is allocated to which objects? Forget about tracemalloc, objgraph, memory-profiler which won't work, and of course the official tensorflow profiler which doesn't have a documentation.  Let's say the leak won't happen unless there is a `tf.function` somewhere, what are the options here?